# How to Transfer PDF from iPad to PC/Mac

Tags: macos, ipad, ios, mac, windows

When I bought an iPad 3 They have given me few pdf files. Actually They are eBook which I prefer. PDF files are shown in the `Books` section of the ITunes program.

How to Transfer those PDFs from my Pad to PC/Mac ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options

- use iTunes to sync. To do this, connect your iOS device to your Mac and launch iTunes. Locate your device from the list that appears on the left column. Now select the tab named "Books". Make sure the sync button is checked. Since Preview is installed by default on iMacs, MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, and Mac Mini, after syncing your PDFs will be accessible from Preview. Benefits of using iTunes to sync is you can manage what PDFs appear on your device (and how much space they take).
- use email. Launch iBooks app on your iOS device and make sure you select the bookshelf view (where your PDFs are displayed on a "shelf"). That means, open the file you want to share. At the top you will see 3 buttons(left to right):

  Library, Index and **Share button**.

  Touch the share button (looks like a folder with an arrow coming out) and then **Email**. Type in your email address and touch Send when done. *Note: some email providers impose limits on attachments so you may have to email PDFs a few at a time.*
- use Dropbox (Dropbox account required). Sign up for a new account at Dropbox.com, then download the free Dropbox app onto your iOS device. Follow the helpful instruction to upload your photos. Note that these PDFs will be available/synced to all Dropbox client apps that log in using your username and password.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more to how get it done ?

Comment: Added clarifications. Let me know if you need more details and I'll add them (driving on the road and unable to type long sentences).

Comment: No problem. Let me know if there is further details needed, and I'll try to answer.

Comment: When I connect to iTunes and enable sync it warns this will delete all books from the device before doing the first sync.

Comment: I tried and it shows the PDFs of my iMac, not of my iPad.  It looks like I can synchronize from mac to ipad only.
Isn't there a way to see the iPad as an external storage device?