# Reverse sync PDF files from iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows, pdf, books

I copied some PDF files from my Windows machine to my iPad via iTunes. I accidentally deleted one PDF from my PC and I would like to copy it back from my iPad. How to do it?

The problem is that the PDF is still listed in my iTunes "PDF" section although it is not physically in my hard drive anymore. It seems that the sync is done only from PC to iPad and not vice versa. If I try to sync the PDFs, I get an error saying that the PDF could not be copied because if was not found.

If I try to remove the PDF from my iTunes PDF collection, the iTunes will warn me that next time I sync, it is removed from my iPad as well.

I'd like to use the email approach from the answer from [How to Transfer PDF from iPad to PC/Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80770/how-to-transfer-pdf-from-ipad-to-pc-mac) but I don't see any "share" button in my iBooks app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Send the PDF by email in iBooks as following:***

Open the PDF you want to transfer in iBooks app.

You will see in top of iBooks(left to right) 3 buttons:

*Library, Index and Share Button.*

Just click in **Share Button**(one of the buttons in the image below), and then **"Email"**.

[image: Share Button]

I hope this helps...